# Why this function component doesn't re-render after setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

As shown below, this `TextInput` component does a simple job: when input's value is empty, hides the title because placeholder shows the same words.

But the code doesn't work as expected. `InputEvent` does run, but reassign `activeStyle` has no effect.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './TextInput.css';
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

type TextInputProps = {
    title: string
}

const TextInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({title, children}) => {

    const hiddenStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 0
    };
    const visibleStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 1
    };
    let activeStyle = hiddenStyle

    const [rawTextInput, setRawTextInput] = useState("")

    const InputEvent = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
        setRawTextInput(inputValue)

        if(inputValue == ""){
            activeStyle = hiddenStyle
        } else {
            activeStyle = visibleStyle
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="TextInput">
            <p 
                className="TextInputTitle"
                style={activeStyle}
            >
                {title}
            </p>
            <input 
                className="TextInputField" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder={title} 
                value={rawTextInput}
                onChange={InputEvent}
            />
            {/*<p className="TextInputHint"></p>*/}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TextInput
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './TextInput.css';
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

type TextInputProps = {
    title: string
}

const TextInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({title, children}) => {

    const hiddenStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 0
    };
    const visibleStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 1
    };
    let activeStyle = hiddenStyle

    const [rawTextInput, setRawTextInput] = useState("")

    const InputEvent = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
        setRawTextInput(inputValue)

        if(inputValue == ""){
            activeStyle = hiddenStyle
        } else {
            activeStyle = visibleStyle
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="TextInput">
            <p 
                className="TextInputTitle"
                style={activeStyle}
            >
                {title}
            </p>
            <input 
                className="TextInputField" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder={title} 
                value={rawTextInput}
                onChange={InputEvent}
            />
            {/*<p className="TextInputHint"></p>*/}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TextInput
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variable doesn't affect re-render.

```
let activeStyle = hiddenStyle    //local variable
```

You need to keep this in state and change using setter method.

```
const [activeStyle, setActiveStyle] = useState(hiddenStyle)

const InputEvent = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    setRawTextInput(inputValue)

    if(inputValue == ""){
        setActiveStyle(hiddenStyle)
    } else {
        setActiveStyle(visibleStyle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a simpler approach

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

type TextInputProps = {
  title: string;
};

const TextInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({ title, children }) => {

  const [rawTextInput, setRawTextInput] = useState("");

  const InputEvent = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setRawTextInput(e.target.value)
  };

  return (
    <div className="TextInput">
      <p className="TextInputTitle" style={{opacity : rawTextInput == ""  ? 0 : 1}}>
        {title}
      </p>
      <input
        className="TextInputField"
        type="text"
        placeholder={title}
        value={rawTextInput}
        onChange={InputEvent}
      />
      {/*<p className="TextInputHint"></p>*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

I hope it'll be useful

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of a local variable does not cause a re-render. And even if something else causes a render, that new render won't have access to local variables from the previous render.  You need to use useState for the active style, not a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

just use useState for activeStyle instead of declaring it on the scope of the component,this could cause unsync effect which could be a problem and indeterministic

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './TextInput.css';
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

type TextInputProps = {
    title: string
}

const TextInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = ({title, children}) => {

    const hiddenStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 0
    };
    const visibleStyle: CSS.Properties = {
        opacity: 1
    };

    const [rawTextInput, setRawTextInput] = useState("")

    //------Put something you want to change dynamically inside useState()
    const [titleStyle, setTitleStyle] = useState(hiddenStyle)
    //------

    const InputEvent = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
        setRawTextInput(inputValue)

        if(inputValue == ""){
            setTitleStyle(hiddenStyle)
        } else {
            setTitleStyle(visibleStyle)
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="TextInput">
            <p 
                className="TextInputTitle"
                style={titleStyle}
            >
                {title}
            </p>
            <input 
                className="TextInputField" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder={title} 
                value={rawTextInput}
                onChange={InputEvent}
            />
            {/*<p className="TextInputHint"></p>*/}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TextInput
```